# Farfield pattern: spherical to cylindrical coordinate projection

Tags: waves, coordinate-systems

The (complex) farfield emission pattern of a near field is defined on a spherical surface with a radius, $r$ approaching $\infty$.

To project this spherical farfield emission onto a plane described using the cylindrical coordinate system one would need to project both the amplitude and the phase of the field. By projection, I don't mean simply plotting a spherical surface on a 2D plane but rather more akin to using a lens to collect the farfield emission. In this case, one could imagine how different points on the spherical wavefront would need to travel difference distances before reaching the lens and thus the need for account for the relative phase change due to the relative difference in the path length.

The amplitude can projected using standard coordinate transformation.
While the additional phase due to the this projected can be considered by an additional phase term: $exp$(ikr $sin \theta$)

For example, to project $E_\theta$ in the spherical coordinates to the radial $E_\rho$ component in the cylindrical coordinates:

$E_\rho^{cyl} = E_{\theta}^{sph}$ $cos$ $\theta$ $exp$ ($ikr$ $sin \theta$)

My question is what value of $r$ do I take? (Maybe not quite the "right" question).

Should there even be an $r$ dependence in this projection given how  the farfield pattern is independent of $r$?

Different values of $r$ will result in different additional phases.
Given how the farfield pattern is independent of $r$ (for large enough $r$), I find it counterintuitive that there should be an $r$ dependence in phase term when projecting to the cylindrical coordinate system. After spending some time thinking about it, I think $r$ needs to take a certain value in order to actually perform the above calculation.

My attempt at understanding this is that even though, the farfield pattern is independent of $r$, it still has to be defined on a sphere with a finite $r$. Regardless of whether the farfield pattern is defined to be at $r$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ or at any finite large value, one can essentially take this to be a unit length and set $r = 1$ i.e. defining the farfield emission on a sphere with 1 unit radius.  While $r = 1$ is still arbitrary, it is probably the most convenient value to take.

Indeed, this is what is being done in the farfield emission output results in my finite difference time domain (FDTD) simulations that I do. In other words, to perform the projection of the farfield emission onto the plane of the lens - including considerations for both the amplitude and the phase - I can take $r = 1$ as this value has been predefined in the simulation results. Is this understanding correct/accurate?

Would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction to get my head around this issue.

Thanks.

[image: Farfield emission collection using a lens]

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply what r you have to choose, you should consider reading the following :http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/fieldRegions.php. 
Generally, the far field region of an antenna is definded as the region where the radiation pattern does not vary with the distance to the source anymore. In the formulas given in the link the maximum linear dimension D of your source will give you an approximate at what distance r your far field region will start.

In your case having a point source might create some trouble here. If you are simulating the pattern numerically, then you must have defined some distance either way I guess. Otherwise, you can just try and see at what distance the radiation pattern is not changing significantly with distance r anymore and take that as a reference for you further calculations.

There also exist other explanations for the field regions grounded on numerical solutions to radiation integrals. If you are interested, the book "antenna theory" by banalis will give you some insight. There the field regions are related to the maximum numerical error in phase of the solution when simplifying parts of the radiation integrals.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your reply. As you said the Farfield emission should be at a distance where there is no longer any dependence on the distance itself. In my case, I have a Fairfield that I am trying to project onto a plane using a lens and I find that somehow the phase of the output emission after the lens depends on r. I wonder if my understanding is correct

Comment: Ok I guess I misunderstood what you were trying to do. So basically you want to use a lense to transform a spherical wave to a plane wave using a lense? Even if you transform the wave to a plane wave it should have an r dependence since the planes, which are parallel to the wavefront are not "parallel" to the wavefronts of you spherical waves. So there must still be a dependence of the wave's phase after the lense on distance r.

Answer (score 0):

For a point source there is no nearfield or farfield pattern.  The radiation is uniform in all directions and its amplitude falls off as 1/r.  Its only needed to find the 'pattern' along any one radial line--it will be the same for any other radial line.  The 'pattern' will not change as a function of r except for the 1/r spherical spreading amplitude attenuation.  This is true for both sinusoidal or pulse type emissions. Here 'pattern' is not a good term to use because it implies angular dependence--whereas with a point source there is none.

So "My question is what value of r do I take? (May be not quite the "right" question)" -- as you say is not the right question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As you said, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to describe a farfield emission pattern for a point source. 
Actually, what I have in mind was a near field and the resulting farfield pattern. 
I have clarified my question. 
Thanks again.